# Operator does not exist: character varying = character varying[]

Tags: sql, postgresql

As you can see in my SQL request I have a subquery which returns string array (`varchar[]`). I am trying to filter `table_1` values by this array which I pass in `ANY` command. For some reason I see this error:

> ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = character varying[]
> No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

The data types of `table_1.column_a` and `table_2.column_a` columns are `varchar`.

PostgreSQL version: `11.4`

Where did I make a mistake?

```
select
    table_1.*
from
    table_1
where
    table_1.column_a = any(
        select
            array_agg(table_2.column_a)
        from
            table_2
    )
```

Of course, I can use such code, but I want to know the reason for the error in the first query:

```
select
    table_1.*
from
    table_1
where
    table_1.column_a in(
        select
            table_2.column_a
        from
            table_2
    )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your subquery:

```
select
    array_agg(table_2.column_a)
from
    table_2
```

returns an array of an array of varchar, *not* an array of varchar. So you are trying to compare a varchar (`table_1.column_a`) with an array of varchar (`array_agg(table_2.column_a)`), which is not possible. Consider if your subquery had an explicit group by clause e.g.

```
select
    array_agg(table_2.column_a)
from
    table_2
group by table_2.column_b
```

In this case it's obvious that the query returns an array of arrays of varchar (one for each `table_2.column_b` value). In your first query, there is an implicit `group by` clause, which results in the output being an array of an array of varchar. You can just use:

```
select
    table_2.column_a
from
    table_2
```

and it will work fine (in this case `= any` is equivalent to `in`).

Answer (score 0):

You already have an array.  So use `exists`:

```
where exists (select 1
              from table_2 t2
              where table_1.column_a = any(t2.column_a)
             )
```

No need to bring the arrays together into a bigger array, just to parse that array to look for another value.